# How can I have all my animations attached to the same object/mesh in unity?

Tags: animation, export, import, unity, .fbx

I am following this tutorial on gun animations [Blender FPS Rigging & Animation Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn8ROcXT8fZgjdv4w6FczF8ziXkavUxdu) and in the video for exporting the animations, he demonstrates exporting the mesh with only the animation, the reload. Due to the fact that the gun drives the motion of the arms, I understand each animation may need to be exported separately from blender. And also because each animation has a different number of keyframes.

However, when I import the FBX into Unity, I would like to have a single mesh with the walk, reload, shoot, idle animations on the same mesh. As it is I would have different meshes each  containing a single animation. This is not ideal at all. It's fine having the gun separate from the arms, that's no problem, but I would have to have multiple guns and multiple arms just to have these few basic animations.

How can I have the arms and gun in unity with all four animations on the same objects, one arm mesh and one gun mesh.

Is this possible? Thanks is advance!

Comment: I would have though that should be a question for a Unity forum rather than a Blender Q&A site?

Comment: Oh I wasn't sure, I thought it would be ok to ask here as I am using blender for the animations and exporting. Could you still offer help ? else I will ask on unity forum

Comment: I don't know much about animation and exporting to fbx files, but it might be worth looking for tutorials on Blender's NLA (Non Linear Animation) editor.

Comment: Can't check it right now, but maybe try the "Alembic" format? It is a bit more powerful, afaik.

Comment: I've been looking up about NLA and Alembic and I don't really know how to apply or use them for my specific problem. Thanks for the suggestions and I will continue to investigate. If anyone has done a similar animation, could you please explain how it's exported for use in Unity. Sure it's a common thing, but hard to find answers.